# Calling function on thread, trying to send command for invalid thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a console application that I developed with c#.
This console run some threads. It always works fine but today I need to call a webbrowser and get some information from a page. I faced some errors and I decided to add this part of my code on a thread.I put my code in a method that named MyBrowserCall. 
I called like this :

```
var t = new Thread(MyBrowserCall);
 t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
 t.Start();
```

This function works fine and everything is good but when i want to call another function in this method I faced this error:

> Unhandled Exception: System.SystemException: Trying to send command
>   from an invalid thread

Do you know how can I fix this ?

Comment: Well, post the code that *threw* that exception and post the ToString output.

Comment: hi @usr , You want to exception ? I wrote here :
Unhandled Exception: System.SystemException: Trying to send command from an invalid thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not fix the issue but I could change my code.

I called the functions that has issue after webbrowser part. So I called GetData function that cause problem after thread of webbrowser. So it is working fine now.